# How to get value of a radio button when selected?

Tags: jquery

I have my html code like this. From this piece of code i would like to get Radio button value when user selects(checked) that value. How to get that value. I got solutions when user clicks on a button or the function has to be called. But i require solution using jQuery when user checks it.

HTML code:

```
<div id="Report_Name" class="leaf">
    <fieldset class="control select multiple" title="">
        <legend>* Select Report Name</legend>
        <ul class="list inputSet sizable">                <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input checked="checked" class="" id="Report_Name1" type="radio" name="Report_Name_option" value="4">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Report_Name1" title="">
                        ALL&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input class="" id="Report_Name2" type="radio" name="Report_Name_option" value="1">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Report_Name2" title="">
                        Cash&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input class="" id="Report_Name3" type="radio" name="Report_Name_option" value="2">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Report_Name3" title="">
                        FDR&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
                            <li>
                <div class="control radio">
                    <input class="" id="Report_Name4" type="radio" name="Report_Name_option" value="3">
                    <label class="wrap" for="Report_Name4" title="">
                        Summary&nbsp;
                    </label>
                </div>
            </li>
            &nbsp;</ul>
    </fieldset>
    <span class="warning"></span>
    <div class="resizeOverlay hidden"></div>
    <div class="sizer vertical" style="position: relative;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-grip-solid-horizontal"></span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Im confused by the classname `multiple`, do you know a radiobox-group can only have one value?

Comment: @PeterRader, `name="Report_Name_option"` handles that

Comment: @Satpal Exactly, i like to know if Pallavipradeep knows it.

Comment: @PeterRader, OP is using it mate thus I have used it in example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach .change event with Radio Button , so after that you can get the value of checked radio button using :checked

In below code we are filtering radio button by name and attaching change event to it and then finding the checked value of radio

```
$("input:radio[name=Report_Name_option]").change(function(){
  console.log($('input:radio[name=Report_Name_option]:checked').val());

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the [**.change()**](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event with radio button. Then you can use [**:checked**](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) Selector to find the selected radio option.

*Example*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(':radio[name="Report_Name_option"]').change(function () {
        alert($(':radio[name="Report_Name_option"]:checked').val())
    })
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7yD2M/)

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search I found a pretty much complete answer for you. Anyway you want to try something like this:

```
$("input:radio[name=Report_Name_option]").click(function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
});
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$('#Report_Name').find('[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
   console.log(this.value);
});
```

---

You have to find the `radios` in this **`#Report_Name`** div and apply a **`.change()`** event to it and get the value of that radio. As you have one radio selected by default so you can get it with triggering the change event on load.

---

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8XyMm/)

Answer (score 0):

example: <kbd>[Demo in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/kotew/1/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>

```
$(function() {
  $(".inputSet input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    // for every change on the radio selection
    checkRadioSelection();
  });

  // so you get the default selection
  checkRadioSelection();
});

function checkRadioSelection()
{
  var r = $(".inputSet input[type=radio]:checked");
  $(".warning").text("You have selected: " + r.val() );
}
```